# REBUILD - Clustered Index, TABLE, or both?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, optimization, fragmentation

I'm having trouble finding a definitive resource on this anywhere, so hopefully a guru can give me an answer here.

I have a very large table that we had to add a column to.  The clustered index is pretty highly fragmented, and I want to do an `ALTER INDEX REBUILD` to clean it up.

I also normally do an `ALTER TABLE REBUILD` when I change the columns since this cleans up any pointers or splits from that operation.

**Do I need to do both since we are talking about a the clustered index, which is essentially the table?**

My suspicion is the `ALTER INDEX REBUILD` on the clustered will not update everything that the `ALTER TABLE` will, but I also am afraid that the `ALTER TABLE` won't clean up the index fragmentation.

Comment: IIRC rebuild won't update column statistics. Doubt that is relevant since it won't happen in either case. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you rebuild the clustered index there shouldn't be any need to rebuild the table.  If the table was a heap (didn't have a clustered index) then you might want to rebuild it.

Comment: I read previously that when you remove a column, you need to do an `ALTER TABLE REBUILD` since this will fix pointers not fixed in the index rebuild.  Is this no longer the case?

Comment: What pointers? I've never heard that.  Removing a column doesn't have any pointers, unless you are talking about TEXT, NTEXT, IMAGE data types in SQL 2000.

Comment: I think my concerns are unfounded then...

Comment: @JNK: I suspect you mean DBCC CLEANTABLE when droppimg columns which is the same as rebuilding the clustered index http://stackoverflow.com/a/808368/27535 and http://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=%2BDBCC+%2BCLEANTABLE

Answer (score 0):

[Rebuild drops and recreates the index.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188388.aspx) When you create a clustered index, [it reorders the rows of a table](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic442511-360-1.aspx) in addition to creating the CIX (a table with no CIX is a heap).

Comment: Rebuild does not drop and recreate the clustered index. Dropping the clustered index turns the table into a heap. IF the rebuild would 'drop and recreate' there would have to be an intermediate state in which the table is a heap, which is not true. If you don't believe me that there is no intermediate heap stage, consider that had such intermediate heap state be achieved the 'recreate' would require a sort, but a quick look at the rebuild execution plan reveals there is no sort.

Comment: Best regards to you RR, I enjoy reading your posts, but I'm not sure why you would argue this point. I already linked the official MSDN. From the "Rebuilding Indexes" section about half way down, 1st statement: "Rebuilding an index drops and re-creates the index." There is no ambiguity in that statement. Here it is again: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188388.aspx

Comment: BOL and MSDN may have poor choice of wording form time to time, and then time and time again... This would be such a case.